Change text size with MenuExtraBar in SwiftUI
Consider this MenuBarExtra created for a macOS-application:
MenuBarExtra {
    Text("Test")
} label: {
    HStack {
        Image(systemName: "folder.fill")
        Text("01:39:22")
    }
}
.menuBarExtraStyle(.window)

The result will look like this:

First: For me the icon and the Text are not in the same line, this looks weird. But adding padding to the icon or the text does not change anything.
Second: The text is too big and I would like to reduce it. Somehow the .font-modifier doesn't have any effect on the text.
MenuBarExtra {
    Text("Test")
} label: {
    HStack {
        Image(systemName: "folder.fill")
        Text("01:39:22")
            .font(.system(size: 7))   // <---- does not work
    }
}
.menuBarExtraStyle(.window)

Any ideas? Or is this impossible with MenuBarExtra?
Just for comparison, please have a look to the text of the VPN-icon (I would like to have the same size):

